# Efficiently finding all possible unique permutations of a word

Tags: python, algorithm, math, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Lets say I have the following word : "aabb" then all possible unique permutations are : "aabb","abab","baba","abba","baab" and "bbaa". Notice that that there are not 4! = 24 ways to do so but 4 choose 2 = 6. What I currently have is a naive approach : finding all permutations, including the duplicates, and afterwards deleting the duplicates :

```
def permutations(l):
    if len(l) <=1:
        yield l
    else:
        for p in permutations(l[1:]):
            for i in range(len(l)):
                yield p[:i] + l[0] + p[i:]

print(set(permutations("aabb")))
```

My question is if their exists a more efficient way to find all these permutations?

EDIT : i do NOT want an approach which follows the inefficient idea of finding all permutations and afterwards deleting the duplicates. My code sample does this already!

EDIT : coldspeed correctly marked my question as duplicate. The correct answer would be to use sympy's multiset_permutations function :

```
>>> from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations
>>> list(multiset_permutations([1,1,1]))
[[1, 1, 1]]
>>> list(multiset_permutations([1,1,2]))
[[1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1]]
```

, per @Bill Bell.

Comment: Do you want to get all the permutations or just their total number? In the latter case there is a simple formula for that

Comment: I want them all. I know of multinomial coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `permutations` from `itertools`. The `set` returns you the unique elements and then you use `join` to get the strings as a single element. The list comprehension way to do this is following.

```
from itertools import permutations
result = [''.join(lst) for lst in set((permutations("aabb")))]
print (result)
```

**Output**

```
['aabb', 'baba', 'bbaa', 'abab', 'abba', 'baab']
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my implementation?

Comment: This is an inbuilt module in itertools which does the same task at the end as you are doing. I do not exactly know under the hood algorithm. You can have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can use [permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and `set()` to remove duplicates

```
from itertools import permutations
res=set()
for i in permutations('aabb'):
    res.add(i)
```

Output

```
set([('b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b')])
```

If list of strings is desired result

```
map(''.join,set(permutations('aabb')))
```

Output

```
['baba', 'bbaa', 'abba', 'aabb', 'baab', 'abab']
```

Comment: OP's current method is faster than this.(14 µs) This answer takes 15.7 µs

Comment: This is also the same as my implementation.

Comment: @DanielScott: That depends on the size of the strings. For ex. try comparing the times for this string `"aabbcdahgfa"` instead of `'aabb'`. Here my answer took 5.66 seconds and OP's method took 21.5 seconds